# Why Mann-Whitney stat value is different in R and Python?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, python, inference, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm calculating Mann-Whitney for a two-sided hypothesis and I'm getting different values for the statistic value:

in **R**

`wilcox.test(Rating~Type,data=R_tapDifficulty, alternative="two.sided")`

> Wilcoxon rank sum test with continuity correction
>
> data:  Rating by Type
>
> W = 200, p-value = 5.881e-10 alternative
>
> hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0

in **Python**

```
stat, p = mannwhitneyu(data1, data2, alternative='two-sided')
print(f'Statistics={stat}, p={p}')
```

> Statistics=1400.0, p=5.880690783826438e-10

Any idea why W(in R) and stat(in Python) are different?

Comment: Please consult the `R` help page for `wilcox.test` and read the section headed "Note."

Comment: @whuber:  I didn't confirm the values, but I suppose you are certain. Thanks

Comment: I am not certain because I haven't tested the Python application--but it looks like that's something you could readily check.